# Pytest incorrectly reports missing lines in coverage

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

I have a pytest suite with several tests. Most of them work just fine - one I just added works, but the coverage report says it's not hitting certain lines in my code. I stepped through the test, and it does in fact hit those lines (which I was certain of - the test would not work otherwise.)

Trying to minimize my code, this is the test:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_update_pydantic_object(async_client: AsyncClient):
    async with async_session_factory() as async_session:
        updated_regional_threshold = schema.PydanticSchema(
            id="test",
            number = 0.35
        )

        res = await update_pydantic_object(session=async_session, orm_type=RegionalThreshold, pydantic_type=schema.PydanticSchema, orm_instances=[updated_pydantic_object])

        assert res[0].number = 0.35
```

And this is the method it claims it's missing lines from:

```
async def update_pydantic_object(
    session: AsyncSession, orm_type: ORMType, pydantic_type: Type[PydanticType], orm_instances: List[schema.PydanticSchema]
) -> List[Any]:
    results = []
    for instance in orm_instances:
        pydantic_object = await get_pydantic_object(instance.id, instance.number, session, orm_type)

        try:
            async with session.begin():
                pydantic_instance = orm_type(**instance.__dict__)

                pydantic_object.number = pydantic_instance.number

                results.append(pydantic_instance)
                await session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
            raise e

    return [pydantic_type.from_orm(i) for i in results]
```

I don't know if this code helps but I had to take out personal stuff. Where could this problem be coming from?

Comment: This usually happens when the function is imported before coverage has started tracking imports.

Comment: I saw that in one or two places, but couldn't find a solution. Do you know how I can make sure that coverage is imported before this test? It's the last test in my suite so that surprises me

Comment: Standalone `coverage` is reporting the same thing... I stepped through the test, and it stepped into the lines it's reporting missing

Comment: You can add `traceback.print_stack()` in the uncovered spots (start with module level) and run `pytest` with the `-s` flag. This will log the trace when the module is imported/the function is invoked and give you some insight on who is importing/calling them and when.

Comment: Other than that, it's hard to give any meaningful advice without having a [mcve].

Comment: Not quite my issue but figured it out. Thank you for the help regardless

Answer (score 1):

So my problem ended up being that my test was not completely self contained. In a previous test, I added a row to my db. And in this test, I used that row. The fix was instead, wiping the table in this test and readding that row.

I'm not sure exactly why that's not allowed, but since the row WAS there, it does explain why the test was working, and why I was able to step into the lines that weren't being reported as covered.

Unsatisfying solution, but going forward all my tests will be completely self contained.

Comment: Tests usually need to be self contained. Main reason for that is because test order is not warranted, unless you actually go out of your way to force your test runner to run them in order.